# Putting hyperlink in RDLC report asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, rdlc

I want to put hyperlink  "VIEW MORE" in RDLC's column ""MESSAGE , upon clicking that URL it show load the remaining text in another page or inline. So how should i do it ?

IMAGE:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the report and click on the cell, choose "Text box Properties".  There is an "Action" option where you can specify an hyperlink with an expression.